# how can debugg field id error in the database schema?

Tags: django, sqlite

TypeError at /contact2/
Field 'id' expected a number but got datetime.datetime(2024, 3, 31, 9, 52, 52, 728466, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact2/
Django Version: 4.2.7
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
Field 'id' expected a number but got datetime.datetime(2024, 3, 31, 9, 52, 52, 728466, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).
Exception Location: C:\Users\Hamprey Aganyo Ndemo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields_*init*_.py, line 2055, in get_prep_value
Raised during:  djangoagain.views.contact
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Hamprey Aganyo Ndemo\PycharmProject\djangoagain\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.12.0
Python Path:
['C:\Users\Hamprey Aganyo Ndemo\PycharmProject\djangoagain',
'C:\Users\Hamprey Aganyo '
'Ndemo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python312.zip',
'C:\Users\Hamprey Aganyo '
'Ndemo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\DLLs',
'C:\Users\Hamprey Aganyo '
'Ndemo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib',
'C:\Users\Hamprey Aganyo Ndemo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312',
'C:\Users\Hamprey Aganyo Ndemo\PycharmProject\djangoagain\venv',
'C:\Users\Hamprey Aganyo '
'Ndemo\PycharmProject\djangoagain\venv\Lib\site-packages',
'C:\Users\Hamprey Aganyo '
'Ndemo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 31 Mar 2024 09:52:54 +0000

to access the database